# Availability calculation of a Event driven Microservice Architecture

Tags: microservices, high-availability, event-sourcing, availability

I have 2 microservices - "A" produces some data which is event Sourced and is replicated in microservice "B". I have a UI which talks to an API sitting on top of microservice "B" which internally uses the replicated data from "A". I have done the Availability calculation individually for both the microservices - let's say 99.5% and 99.8%. How do I calculate the Availability for the whole system? For example, if "A" is down and "B" is up, users still see the APIs working from B albeit with stale data from "A". I shouldn't be the first one to have stumbled upon this scenario...

Comment: The whole system has: 99.5% x 99.8% = 99.301%

Comment: Yours is correct for an SOA based Architecture wherein "B"'s availability is dependant on "A" availability. As I have mentioned, I do have a copy of the latest data which was event-sourced from A in B until the time A was up and running..

Comment: How do you define the availability of a system? Stale data means the system is available or unavailable?

Comment: Yes...that's the whole point of discussion. Event Driven Architecture provides this cushion for me to make the Microservice B work with the latest data from A. If A isn't supposed to send new data between X:00 am to Y:00 am; although A is down while B is up, technically I am serving the latest data. I hope I am not the first person to run into something like this.

Comment: the definition of availability is based on your business. If the business considers a microservice that uses remote stale data as available then the overall availability is then the *minimum* of all independent microservices.

Comment: Event-driven architectural style is just an implementation detail. You could have the same problem if you use a `cron` job that copies remote data into local cache.

Answer (score 1):

Let's describe two options:

1) *Your customer needs the freshest data* (evaluation of some eligibilities, real-time evaluation, etc.):
The microservices are dependent on each other therefore **you have to multiply both availabilities 99.8% x 99.5% = 99.3%**

2) *Your customer does not need the freshest data* (most probably some report generation):
You can claim the availability of the system as 99.8%.

Comment: So why to multiply? You calculated the chance both being available? The question is about B showing stale data from A.